# Do people release their mobile apps and then add the ad code ?

Tags: android, admob, ads

New to mobile app development and the release process and nearly ready to release my first app. Now I've signed up to use AdMob and some other vendors, but they all want my android market id before I download the SDK. This doesn't make much sense to me, surely developers want to release the app with the ads from the start.

Do developers release the app and then immediately add the ad code? Also, is it necessary to repeatedly to download the SDK/jar files for each app you release ? (I ask this because the vendors ask you to download after you have an app added on their site)

Comment: leave it blank, you will be able to download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do developers release the app and then immediately add the ad code?

The market ID of your app is simply its package name as declared in the manifest.  One option is to upload your app to the market, but do not publish it.  From my understanding, that should "reserve" your package name.  As long as your package name is unique, you should be fine.

> Also, is it necessary to repeatedly to download the SDK/jar files for
>   each app you release

I haven't used Admob, but I know the Flurry SDK is the same jar for each download.

Answer (score 1):

New App developer here.

1. You get the AdMob SDK by putting in your package name: com.example.app and that will never change for your app. You can integrate it right away and see ads within a few minutes.
2. Download the AdMob SDK and just put it in a folder somewhere that won't get moved, and just reference it in your Android Project settings. You don't need to re-download for each app